# what is the purpose of '&' in insert statement while entering multiple records

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Example :

```
 INSERT into values(&id,'&name',&age);
```

While executing the statement , it's showing a popup like 'please enter the substitution variable'

**So my question :** 
what does substitution variable means ? And what is inner process happening with '&' symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**&** symbol indicates to oracle that you want to specify a value for that column before oracle processes the query

Answer (score -2):

& is a Bitwise AND operator, take a look here for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql

Comment: No Roberto , not in this case

Comment: but here we are using for inserting multiple rows. so, how this bitwise operator related to the insertion command?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.